# Добавление записей в связанных таблицах

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Прошу помочь с небольшим вопросом касательно SQL.

**ДАНО** Таблица А и ее дочерняя Б

**УСЛОВИЕ** В Таблице А имеются некоторые записи, но не для всех записей в Б сгенерирована строка и имеется ключ в пользу ухода от избыточности.

**РЕШЕНИЕ** Попытаться считать ключ А в Б, в случае если таковой не имеется сгенерировать запись в Б.

**ПСЕВДОКОД**
SELECT id FROM b WHERE id =(SELECT id FROM A WHERE name = 'TestName')
if result = 0
Записать в Б новый ID и значения
else
Записать значение данному ключу

**ВОПРОС** Есть ли какой-то запрос на языке SQL который позволяет это делать в контексте одного запроса? Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы

Comment: Ответ на вопрос - да, есть.

Comment: @akina отлично! надеюсь, вам не сложно будет привести пример такого запроса

Comment: Не-а... вот когда я увижу конкретные DDL, пример наполнения и желаемый результат - тогда может быть. Потому как из текста вопроса я лично мало что понял.

Comment: @akina В таблице [Names] Есть Varchar строка [Name], в которой содержатся IP и DNSname оборудования в локалке. 
Для Domain PC [TYPE] с помощью c# достаются String - WMI objects и в случае успеха записываются в таблицу [Properties], поля типа [user] [mac]  и т.д
Загвоздка в том, что для новых устройств в [Properties] еще не создана запись

Comment: В таком случае (если нет записи - создать, если есть - обновить), используется MERGE - см. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb510625(v%3dsql.105)

Comment: @akina Пишу запрос в такой форме

MERGE Properties
 USING Names
 ON (Properties.Prop_ID = Names.Name_ID) --Условие объединения
 WHEN MATCHED 
 THEN --Если истина (UPDATE)
   UPDATE SET [User] = 'Тут произвольные данные из переменной'
 WHEN NOT MATCHED 
 THEN --Если НЕ истина (INSERT)
   INSERT (Prop_ID, [user]) 
   VALUES (Names.Name_ID, 'Тут произвольные данные из переменной 2');


При этом заполняются все [User], нехватающее поле с ключом создается, информация вносится
Что не так пишу?

Comment: @Семён все работает именно так, как Вы написали. В чем собственно проблема? (Это я про запрос) Подозреваю, что в `'Тут произвольные данные из переменной' ` нужно подставлять разные значения для каждой строки.